# openStack - Package : keyStone error requires a different python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, openstack, devstack, openstack-keystone

i want to install openStack on ubuntu 16.04 when i enter the command `**./stack.sh**` i get the following error

`ERROR: Package 'keystone' requires a different Python: 3.5.2 not in '>=3.6'`

python version  is 2.7.12 , i also read the openstack.org documentaion, it said in Prerequisites that use to up version 2.7.

Each time I get error, I re-enter the following commands:
 `**./unstack.sh**

 **./clean.sh**

**./stack.sh**`
But I get the same error again

Comment: Python 2 is end-of-life. I expect modern openstack installs probably require Python 3.x.

Comment: I also installed version 3 but it didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add "**USE_PYTHON3=True**" parameter to your local.conf, it should work